# How to change start day of week of DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I used DatePickerDialog to allow user pick a day.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.TUESDAY);
new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

I used method **setFirstDayOfWeek** in order to set start day of week is Tuesday, but the Dialog Picker always show Monday on the left side.

[image]

How can I set start day of week for DatePickerDialog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though I don't know of any locale that uses Tuesday as the first day of week, here's how to set the first day of week.

Instead of setting the first day of week of `Calendar`, you need to set the first day of week of the date picker inside the date picker dialog.

So you first need to get the date picker by calling [`getDatePicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#getDatePicker()), then call [`setFirstDayOfWeek`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setFirstDayOfWeek(int)):

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
dialog.getDatePicker().setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.TUESDAY);
dialog.show();
```